# Problem with the delimiter of data packet

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following example reads data from the UART. In my case, the delimiter where packet starts with b '\x02' everything works, but the problem appears when b '\x02' appears in the packet and it is not the beginning of the packet because uart data often comes in one string. I will add that the packet that needs to be read always starts with b '\x02\x84' the only question is how to check if the first byte b '\x02’  followed by b '\x84' and if so then do a split.

Sample package consisting of several and with the problem:

> \x02\x84"\x00\x19\x03\x00l\xe0\x02D\x00\x02\x84"\x00\x19\x03\x00l

I want to get two as handle_packet:

> b'\x84"\x00\x19\x03\x00l\xe0\x02D\x00'

> b'\x84"\x00\x19\x03\x00l'

```
rx_buff = bytes()

while True:
    recv = reader.read(-1)
    if not recv:
        continue

    rx_buff += recv

    packets = rx_buff.split(bytes(b'\x02'))

    for packet in packets:
       if not packet:
           continue
 
       msg = mod.handle_packet(packet)
       if (msg):
           get_response(msg)

    rx_buff = (bytes() if mod.handle_packet(packet) else packet)
```

Comment: It looks like you can just split it, no? `my_bytes = b'\x02\x84"\x00\x19\x03\x00l\xe0\x02D\x00\x02\x84"\x00\x19\x03\x00l'`, `split_bytes = my_bytes.split(b'\x02\x84"')`, then add the leading byte back when you need it, `b'\x84"' + split_bytes[1]`.

Comment: yes, but the problem will be when the last byte of the string is "\ x02" and the next one gets b"\ x84"

Comment: I must be missing something then. When I split it, I can recreate the 2 packets that you want. I will post an answer, because I don't think comments will do justice.

Comment: Well, if a data packet can be broken across TCP packets, then you will have to check for `b'\x02` being the last byte, and remove it and save it to be prepended to the next packet.  This is a common pattern in TCP.

Comment: if you get `\x02` as last byte then you can't split but you have to wait for rest of data.

Comment: Can I ask for an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a little more time reading. If you do it this way, your problem is going to be the first packet you split, because, I am assuming it doesn't follow the splitting pattern `b'\x02\x84"`. If that is the case, you can just take the first of split_bytes and remove the first byte.

```
my_bytes = b'\x02\x84"\x00\x19\x03\x00l\xe0\x02D\x00\x02\x84"\x00\x19\x03\x00l'
split_bytes = my_bytes.split(b'\x02\x84"')
packets = []
for e in split_bytes:
    if e != b'':
        packets.append(b'\x84"' + e)

print(packets)
```

Yields:

```
[b'\x84"\x00\x19\x03\x00l\xe0\x02D\x00', b'\x84"\x00\x19\x03\x00l']
```

Your desired packets:

```
[b'\x84"\x00\x19\x03\x00l\xe0\x02D\x00', b'\x84"\x00\x19\x03\x00l']
```

If I am missing something, please point it out.

Comment: @artm if this is the correct answer, would you please mark it as so?